# Cassandra inconsistencies in batch inserts/updates

Tags: c#, .net, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax

I am getting the following error message:
`Cassandra timeout during write query at consistency ONE (0 replica(s) acknowledged the write over 1 required)`

I am using Cassandra with an replication factor of 3.
Everything is working like as it should. But lately, I found an error. Maybe it occurs in Cassandra or in the datastax c# cassandra driver I am using.

To be 100% sure, I set in my tests all ConsistencyLevel-possiblities to `ConsistencyLevel.Quorum`. But I also tried `ConsistencyLevel.Two`.

The Problem occurred with both settings.

**My problem is not the timeout, this is something I can solve.
I am concerned about the fact that I get an error message saying that 1  acknowledge (consistency ONE) is required. Although I set everything to `ConsistencyLevel.Quorum` or `ConsistencyLevel.Two`.**

Without the WriteTimeoutException I never would have noticed, that maybe there is an consistency problem.

I also used tracing and got the following (deeper) error:

`Cassandra.Session:  RequestHandler received exception Cassandra.WriteTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during write query at consistency ONE (0 replica(s) acknowledged the write over 1 required)`

Here is some test code:

```
var cluster =  Cluster.Builder().AddContactPoints("192.168.0.1", "192.168.0.2", "192.168.0.3", "192.168.0.4", "192.168.0.5")
.WithQueryOptions(new QueryOptions().SetConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.Quorum))
.WithCompression(CompressionType.LZ4).Build();
var session = cluster.Connect();
insertStatementTableX = session.Prepare(
   "INSERT INTO keyspace.x (a, b, c) VALUES (?, ?, ?);").SetConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.Quorum);
insertStatementTableY = session.Prepare(
   "INSERT INTO keyspace.y (a, b, c) VALUES (?, ?, ?);").SetConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.Quorum);
var batch = new BatchStatement();
batch.SetConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.Quorum);   
batch.Add(insertStatementTableX.Bind(1, 2, 3)).SetConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.Quorum);
batch.Add(insertStatementTableY.Bind(2, 3, 4)).SetConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.Quorum);
session.Execute(batch);
```

Can I assume, that all other inserts/updates now are also done with consistency level ONE although I set it to quorum?
Or is just the error message wrong?

Comment: what version of the driver are you using? could be this bug https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/CSHARP-206

Comment: or this one https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/CSHARP-231

Comment: I am using 2.5.2. Via NuGet I should have the newest version. I don't know if just the error-reporting is wrong, or the submitting to cassandra. Do you have an idea how I could figure that out?

Comment: If you're on the latest version can you file a jira? Let us know the #

Comment: Hello, I have created a bug report: 307

Answer (score 0):

In Cassandra, for write operations, [a timeout is not a failure](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/how-cassandra-deals-with-replica-failure).

It means that time passed for the coordinator waiting for the actual replica to respond that the write succeeded.

It is not yet available for read but it was written to the batch log and you should not make the client retry. If you are looking for low latency and a guarantee that a write never fails (highest availability), you can change the write [consistency to ANY](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/dml/dml_config_consistency_c.html).

Comment: My data is not updated. I am using an insert to override some values. And these values are still in the old format. 
However, this is not the problem. I am concerned about the fact, that I set ConsistencyLevel.Quorum or ConsistencyLevel.Two but the error message says that it got a timeout with ConsistencyLevel.One.
So, either the request was sent to Cassandra with ConsistencyLevel.One, or the c# driver is wrong and is ignoring the fact that ConsistencyLevel was set to something else than "One".